# What is the correct way to reference a boolean parameter in SSM document for powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-ssm

I am trying to create an SSM document that deals with parameters but I am getting

Here is my Parameter block :

```
        "createfoo":{
            "type": "Boolean",
            "description": "Do you want to Create foo",
            "default": false
        }
```

Here is my runCommand block :

```
        "mainSteps": [
            {
                "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
                "name": "InstallGAIN",
                "inputs":{
                    "runCommand": [ 
                        "[bool] $createfoo={{createfoo}}",
                        "if ($createfoo -eq $true) {",
                        "Write-Host \"Creating foo\"",
                         "}"

] } ]
```

> Update-SSMDocument : Parameter "createfoo" is "BOOLEAN" type and can't be used as a
> substring parameter.
> At line:2 char:21
>
> - $latestDocVersion = Update-SSMDocument
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...MDocumentCmdlet:UpdateSSMDo
>     cumentCmdlet) [Update-SSMDocument], InvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model.InvalidDocumentContentExcep
>     tion,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.SSM.UpdateSSMDocumentCmdlet

Following is the command that I run to update my doc

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "installFoo.ssm" | Out-String
$latestDocVersion = Update-SSMDocument `
    -Content $content `
    -Name "installFoo" `
    -DocumentFormat "JSON" `
    -DocumentVersion '$LATEST' `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LatestVersion

Update-SSMDocumentDefaultVersion `
    -Name "installFoo" `
    -DocumentVersion $latestDocVersion
```

Comment: @mklement0  Thank you, The problem is not in the way I update the SSM document, but how I am trying to use the Parameter's (createfoo) value (false) inside runcommand block.

Comment: Based on the error message and skimming the docs (I'm not familiar with AWS Systems Manager), it looks like embedding a Boolean parameter inside a string isn't allowed, yet you need to pass the PowerShell code as a single string (right?). Perhaps you can define the parameter as a _string_ instead. Note that even if the expansion of `createFoo` in `[bool] $createfoo={{createfoo}}` were permitted, it wouldn't work _in PowerShell_, because something like `[bool] $createfoo=true` would look for `true` as a _command_; `0` or `1` would work

Comment: If `{{createfoo}}` expands to a string value of `true` or `false`, you'd have to use something like `[bool] $createfoo= if ('true' -eq '{{createfoo}}') { $true } else { $false }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by passing True/False value as string as suggested in comments by mklment0.
Here is how paramater block looks like no :

```
        "createfoo":{
            "type": "String",
            "description": "Do you want to Create foo",
            "default": "false"
        }
```

Also the `runCommand` block :

```
        "mainSteps": [
            {
                "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
                "name": "InstallGAIN",
                "inputs":{
                    "runCommand": [ 
                        "if ({{createFoo}} -eq 'true') {",
                        "Write-Host \"Creating foo\"",
                         "}"

] } ]
```